# Collect data for duplicate ids into an array of custom type

Tags: swift

I have a list of tuples, with repeated "ids":

```swift
var tuples: [(Int, String)] = [
    (1, "A"),
    (1, "B"),
    (1, "C"),
    (2, "X"),
    (2, "Y"),
    (1, "Z")
]
```

I'd like to collect them into an array of custom `Bag` type:

```swift
struct Bag {
    let id: Int
    var names: [String]
}

let desiredResult = [
    Bag(id: 1, names: ["A", "B", "C", "Z"]),
    Bag(id: 2, names: ["X", "Y"])
]
```

What is the most performant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I assume your desired result `id: 2` should be `X, Y` not `Y, Z`

Comment: @jnpdx Yes, thank you. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In Swift 5, the easiest implementation would be to use the native `Dictionary(grouping:by:)`, which groups the value like you want, and then use `map` to create your array of bags:

```swift
Dictionary(grouping: tuples, by: \.0)
    .map { Bag(id: $0.key, names: $0.value.map(\.1)) }
```

Some simple explanations: `Dictionary(grouping: tuples, by: \.0)` groups your `tuples` array using the first element (`.0`), which results in a dictionary like:

```swift
let tuplesGrouped: [Int: [(Int, String)]] = [
    1: [(1, "A"), (1, "B"), (1, "C"), (1, "Z")],
    2: [(2, "X"), (2, "Y")],
]
```

The later `map` acts on the type `[(key: Int, value: [(Int, String)])]`, which is then used to create the array of `Bag`s.

Comment: S'good but it's strange to see a closure in one place and a key path in the other. `(grouping: tuples, by: \.0)` would be more consistent.

Comment: @Jessy Fair enough! I do agree with the sentiment, and I also love consistency, so I've updated the code to match what you've mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Both `Dictionary` and `OrderedDictionary` are currently missing the initializer that you need to do this:

```swift
OrderedDictionary(grouping: tuples).map(Bag.init)
```

There are no protocols that will make it easy to write them for both types. Your use case seems to be a better match for [`OrderedDictionary`](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections).

```swift
import struct Collections.OrderedDictionary

public extension OrderedDictionary {
  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Either `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`
  ///   or a `Sequence` with the same element type as that.
  /// - Returns: `[KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value]]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (key: Key, value: Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self =
      OrderedDictionary<Key, [KeyValuePairs.Element]>(grouping: pairs, by: \.key)
      .mapValues { $0.map(\.value) }
  }

  /// Group key-value pairs by their keys.
  ///
  /// - Parameter pairs: Like `Swift.KeyValuePairs<Key, Self.Value.Element>`,
  ///   but with unlabeled elements.
  /// - Returns: `[KeyValuePairs.Key: [KeyValuePairs.Value]]`
  init<Value, KeyValuePairs: Sequence>(grouping pairs: KeyValuePairs)
  where
    KeyValuePairs.Element == (Key, Value),
    Self.Value == [Value]
  {
    self.init( grouping: pairs.map { (key: $0, value: $1) } )
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple/naive implementation (which looks for an existing match to append against, otherwise it appends to the top array:

```swift
var desired = [Bag]()
for tuple in tuples {
    if let index = desired.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == tuple.0 }) {
        desired[index].names.append(tuple.1)
    } else {
        desired.append(Bag(id: tuple.0, names: [tuple.1]))
    }
}
```